# There are no ~ / There are not ~

Tags: word-usage

All I know about "NO" is like this.

There are no movies playing on Christmas day.

=>There are not any movies playing on Christmas day.

=>We won't be showing any movies on Christmas day.

And here's what I'd like to ask.

As I don't want to wast my time doing nothing at home, I usually make my way to a place where I can do something productive.

> 1. So, there **are not many** things that I do at home.
> 2. So, there **are no many** things that I do at home.

Here, I think #1 is right because #2 means "there are not any many things that I do at home" and this sounds awkward and not grammatically right. Am I right to think this way?

Comment: *..things that I do...* or *..things that I can do...*? I think it is *can*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*No* is a quantifier, like *one*, *some*, *many*, *much*, *few*, *three*.  We don't combine quantifiers except in mathematical expressions (*one hundred*, *three dozen*)<sup>†</sup>, so *no many* is illegitimate.

*Not* is a negator. It **can** be combined with quantifiers (*not much*, *not one*) and other word classes (*not difficult*, *not quickly*, *not a question*). Generally, however, we prefer to 'raise' the negator in a predicate and attach it to the verb, just as we prefer to 'raise' it out of a subordinate clause into a main clause. The unraised versions tend to be employed only to emphasize where exactly the negation lies.

> <sup>∗</sup> We will be showing not any movies on Christmas day.
> <sup>ok</sup>We will not be showing any movies on Christmas day.
>
> <sup>?</sup> I think that we won't be showing any movies on Christmas day.
> <sup>ok</sup>I don't think that we will be showing any movies on Christmas day.

---

<sup>†</sup> You will see expressions like *No three of them could lift the rock*. Here *no* doesn't combine with *three*, it quantifies the entire following NP; that is, this sentence is equivalent to "No set of three of them could lift the rock".

Answer (score 2):

You can not use **no** before **many** and **much**.

You should use **not** before them.

Answer (score 1):

You can regard **no = not any**

> There is **not any** thing that I can do at home
>
> There is **no** thing (or nothing) that I can do at home

but if there is something (even few) you should use other quantifers

Here, **few == not many**

> There are **few** things that I can do at home

equals

> There are **not many** things that I can do at home