# Which one is sentence correct between "why does it do not good" and "why does it do no good"?

Tags: grammar

I want to know Which one is sentence correct between "why does it do not good" and "why does it do no good"? I'm so confusing this.

Comment: How about, neither? You're missing a verb. A "do".

Comment: It's not clear what meaning you're trying to convey. Maybe "why doesn't it do any good"?

Comment: I'm not sure the first of your options can ever be grammatical, but we need more context. What are you trying to say?

Comment: which one is correct? neither?

Comment: Check [this](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/63107/32) out and see if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the sentences are correct. Compare the following two examples.

- > I have no book.

  <no, an adjective; qualifying book>
- > I have not a book.

  <not, an adverb; modifying the verb, 'have'>

In these instances functionality becomes all the more obvious for article "a" as it does come between 'not' and 'book'.

Do remember the difference. It is never ambiguous. For better understanding, we would write the first sentence like this:

> Why doesn't it do good?

It would be proper to take 'not' before the subject if the subject is a pronoun.

Comment: It's hard to be sure whether the OP was asking about *potential grammatical correctness* or *the proper sentence to use for a given meaning*. If the latter, this answer doesn't help much.

Answer (score 0):

You can say *why does it do no good*

as an informal way of saying:

> Why doesn't it help.

Beyond that, you need to add context to see how it works in a particular situation.

I can't see any way that this one makes sense:

> why does it do not good

especially the *do not good* part.